# Try to find again an Illustrator file I opened recently

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I opened an Illustrator file the other day that I found quite back accident while searching for another file. Now that I am purposefully trying to find it, Of course I cannot. Unfortunately I don't remember what it I named it. But considering I just opened it it should not be all that hard to find again? But it is proving to be more difficult than I thought.

The problem is that only the filename and not the full filepath is displayed. So for files with similar names, I'll have a hard time finding the right folder.

Any suggestions please. Thank you.

Comment: I thought nothing about it at the time. Until I was watching a video about typography so I went looking for the file again. Not realizing I would have trouble locating it. I suppose that I should add that it is not something I created recently but rather years ago.

Comment: Your operating system has likely a way to search files using the last access time as a criterion. This in combination with a file extension should return a manageable list of files to check. But how to do this on  your specific OS is a question for SuperUser, not GraphicDesign.

Comment: Thank you Xenoid. Sorry if I asked my question in the wrong place. I don't know how to ask "SuperUser"

Comment: Here: [https://superuser.com/questions](https://superuser.com/questions)

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at your recent files list under 'File → Open Recent Files'.

Comment: That was like one of the first things I did, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Not much else AI can help you with then. This is like asking _where did i put my salt_ on a cooking website.

Comment: @Lucian - it's where you left it!

Comment: Not exactly. I asked about trying to find a file I created years ago and just opened the other day. But now that I am trying to find it again I can't. I thought it would be easy considering I just opened it. I was just asking if there was a way to find it again? Considering the first time was by accident. By the way I know where my salt is  @ Lucian it is in the kitchen!

Comment: So asking a question/advice on how to relocate an Adobe file you accidentally found to begin with that you created years ago is not permissible and therefore frowned upon? That is generally why I usually come here as an absolute last resort!